# Is the extended security framework a useful model for modern security phenomena?

Tags: political-theory, national-security

First, I am referring to working paper from Christopher Daase (2010).

> Daase, Christopher (2010): Der erweiterte Sicherheitsbegriff. Working
>   Paper 1. Sicherheitskultur im Wandel

His paper describes for dimensions: Threat dimension (Risk, vulnerability, Threat), Geographical dimension (Global, International, Regional, National), Subject dimension (Humanitarian, Ecological, Economical, Military) and Reference dimension (Individual, Society, State). 
Each of the dimensions have three or four parts which specify the different levels or categories.

In his paper he refers himself to the criticism of an overly broad security framework, catching everything and therefore nullifying it because everything has been made a security issue. In other words, if everything is a security issue, is the framework useless (P. 9).

Therefore, did somebody encounter the extended security framework in their studies or professional working day? 
If so, what was the approach to the framework?

I am looking forward to your answers.

Comment: I have added political-theory tag as this seem to be related to theory rather than an actual political issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not find anything really suitable and did not think about that option.